# Is there a cleaner way to deal with double nullable types in F#?

Tags: f#

I have these two lines:

```
if not start.IsNone && not stop.IsNone then
    let times = TimeArray start.Value stop.Value interval
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? if it's a single value, I can use match, but what about 2 values? (F# day 3 here..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use pattern matching. Consider this quite meaningless example which can help you understand the overall pattern.

```
let start = Some 1
let stop = Some 2    
let res =
    match start, stop with
    | Some _a, Some _b -> (_a,_b)
    | _, _ -> (0, 0)
```